# Why is this code written with TypeScript generics not correct?

Tags: typescript

As I am reading through the documentation, I read that generics are like functions which take in a type and can be extended to fine tune their use.

```
function add<T>(sum : T, num:T): T {
  return sum + num
}

const res = add<number>(1,2)
```

The following code snippet gives an error saying,

```
Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'T' and 'T'.
```

And I am trying to wrap my head around why that is giving an error.

is giving the explicit types the only solution, like below?
example -

```
function add(sum:number, num:number):number {
  return sum + num
}

const res = add(1,2)
```

Comment: The error message is correct. This is a valid call to the function `add<boolean>(true, false)` - the result in this case is not `T` (since `T = boolean`). Moreover, `+` has no meaning between booleans in TS (although JS will coerce the types).

Comment: Oh, setting the type as <number> while calling the function isn't enough to bypass this?

Comment: You can set the type to anything you want when calling this. Including `boolean`. And since the function doesn't work with `boolean` (and the vast majority of other types) the generic does not hold. It's not generic. It literally only works with `number` and `string`. Nothing else. Not even literal types like `"hello"` or `42`

Comment: Oh i understand generics much better now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the generic variable `T` can implicitly be of any type; an `object`, `boolean`, `null`, `undefined` etc. using the `+` operator on it may not valid. Hence you will unfortunately have to be more specific with your types in this situation and only allow ones that can be added e.g. `string | number`.